# How can I visually view an xcode project that has no storyboard file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to understand an app and I'd like to be able to see a visual representation of the project (without running the simulator). It appears the developer didn't use a storyboard in building the app. Is this common? What is a good way to see the views without running the project?

Thanks I'm a pretty serious iOS noob :)

Answer (score 0):

If there's no storyboard, then watch out for .xib file. Those files contain visual representation of a particular class or view controller.

Comment: no xib files :) Is it common for some coders to just write straight code and look at the results in the simulator?

Comment: Ohh. That's the thing. I never saw such thing so I said :)